# Xamarin C# DateTime.ConvertTime() wrong working

Tags: datetime, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am writing Xamarin.iOS app using C#.
I am trying to convert EST timezone time to local timezone time using following code, but it is never converted.

```
TimeZoneInfo eastZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById ("EST");
DateTime convertedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (estDate, eastZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

convertedDate is always same as estDate.
Of course, I am not in EST timezone.
I checked ConvertTime() definition, and found it assumes first parameter is local timezone.

```
    public static DateTime ConvertTime (DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone)
    {
        if (sourceTimeZone == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("sourceTimeZone");
        }
        if (destinationTimeZone == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("destinationTimeZone");
        }
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local && sourceTimeZone != TimeZoneInfo.Local) {
            throw new ArgumentException ("Kind property of dateTime is Local but the sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Local");
        }
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc && sourceTimeZone != TimeZoneInfo.Utc) {
            throw new ArgumentException ("Kind property of dateTime is Utc but the sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc");
        }
        if (sourceTimeZone.IsInvalidTime (dateTime)) {
            throw new ArgumentException ("dateTime parameter is an invalid time");
        }
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local && sourceTimeZone == TimeZoneInfo.Local && destinationTimeZone == TimeZoneInfo.Local) {
            return dateTime;
        }
        DateTime dateTime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc (dateTime);
        if (destinationTimeZone != TimeZoneInfo.Utc) {
            dateTime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc (dateTime2, destinationTimeZone);
            if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
                return DateTime.SpecifyKind (dateTime2, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            }
        }
        return dateTime2;

}
```

.Net System.dll has wrong code?

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing problems with TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime except on Android.

I filed bug 25942 for this on Xamarin's site: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25942

Comment: Are you sure that is the source for .NET's implementation?  It actually works for me on .NET.  It is just broken on Mono.